# Good upper bound on ratio of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, approximation-theory

What is the asymptotic behavior of $n/2+k/2 \choose k$/$n\choose k$ for $k\le n/2$. Can we show that it goes down (sub)exponential in $k$ i.e. $n/2+k/2 \choose k$/$n\choose k$ $\le c^{-k^{\epsilon}}$ for some fixed constant $c>1$ and $\epsilon>0$? For $k\le n/2$, we can upperbound $n/2+k/2 \choose k$/$n\choose k$ by $\frac{3n/4 \choose k}{n \choose k}$, can we get a (sub)exponential in $-k$ upper bound on $\frac{3n/4 \choose k}{n \choose k}$? Thanks.

Comment: standard approximations and numerical experiments suggest that the right hand side decreases sub-exponentially

Comment: @kodlu is there a good estimate for the decrease, like say $c^{-k^{\epsilon}}$ for some small $\epsilon$? What if we look at the ratio of $\frac{3n/4 \choose k}{n \choose k}$, can we give a good upper bound on this?

Comment: @user1131274 Do you mean (constants) $c, \epsilon$ are independent of $n, k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{{n/2+k/2 \choose k}}{{n \choose k}} =\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{L-j}{n-j} \tag1$$

where $L=n/2+k/2 < n$

Now, the factors inside the product are decreasing. Hence we get the upper bound
$ (L/n)^k=c^{-k}$
with $c=2n/(n+k)=\frac{2}{1+t}$ where $t=k/n$

For the record, the (first order) Stirling approxmation gives

$$\frac{{n/2+k/2 \choose k}}{{n \choose k}} \approx (1-t^2)^{n/2} \left(  \frac{1+t}{4(1-t)} \right)^{k/2} $$

Edited:
I tighter bound can be found be bouding each term in $(1)$. I get

$$\frac{{n/2+k/2 \choose k}}{{n \choose k}} \le d^{-k}$$

with
$$d = \frac{2 }{1+t} \exp\left( \frac{(t-1/n)(1-t)}{2 (1+t)} \right) \approx \frac{2 }{1+t} \exp\left( \frac{t(1-t)}{2 (1+t)}\right) $$

Answer (score 2):

Using the gamma function$$A=\frac{\binom{\frac{k+n}{2}}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}=2^{n-k}\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n-k+1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+k+2}{2}
   \right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \,\Gamma (n+1)}$$ Assuming $n\gg k$, take logarithms and use Stirling approximation to obtain
$$\log(A)=-k \log(2)+\frac{k (k+1)}{2 n}\Bigg[ 1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{k (k+1)}{6 n^2}-\frac{k^2+k-1}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\Bigg]$$ which gives good bounds since alternating.

Using $n=25$ and $k=10$, this truncated series gives
$$\log(A) \sim \frac{2078153}{937500}-10 \log (2)=-4.71478$$ to be compared to the exact value
$$\log(A)=-\log \left(\frac{2097152}{18879}\right)=-4.71029$$ which, for $A$, corresponds to a relative error of $0.45$%.

Comment: Thanks. I only know that $k\le n/2$ and want a good upper bound on the ratio. I was thinking of bounding the ratio with $\frac{3n/4 \choose k}{n \choose k}$ and then upper bounding $\frac{3n/4 \choose k}{n \choose k}$ with $c^{-k^{\epsilon}}$ for some fixed small constant $\epsilon$. A bound of $c^{-k^{\epsilon}}$ would be sufficient for my need. Can we get such a bound? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Following @leonbloy, you can get an explicit bound in terms of $k$ as follows. Note that $\frac{L-j}{n-j}=1-\frac{n-L}{n-j}$. Then, using the estimate $1-x\le e^{-x}$ which holds for all positive $x$ we get an estimate of the form
$$
e^{-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{n-L}{n-j}}.
$$
A very rough bound that you can use here now is just noting that $\frac{n-L}{n-j}\ge \frac{n-L}{n} = \frac{n/2-k/2}{n}= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{k}{2n}\ge \frac{1}{4}$ where in the last inequality we have used that $n\ge 2k$. Hence, we have the following bound
$$
\frac{\binom{n/2+k/2}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}\le e^{-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{4}}=e^{-k/4}.
$$

Comment: $\frac{n-L}{n-j}\ge \frac{n-L}{n-(k-1)}$ should be $\frac{n-L}{n-j}\le \frac{n-L}{n-(k-1)}$?

Comment: That's totally true, thanks!, I have just fixed it